# MapResults into Correspanding Objects with CypherDSL

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I am using Neo4jOperations.query(stat,params) method and getting the results from query is completely three different objects. Here I couldn't use Neo4jOperations.query(stat,params).to(...) because query is dependent on three different classes.
So please give your suggestions on this questions to convert the results into three different objects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share some code on what you already tried? And what your query looks like and what it depends on which target type you want to use?

In general the parameter to `to()` is a class which can be derived from any condition including checks of your query. You can also get the raw results and transform them yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My code is:  String query = "MATCH (user)-[f:OFFERS]-(bat) RETURN use, f, bat"; and Iterable<Map<String,Object>> results = engine.query( query, "") or Iterable<Map<String,Object>> results = Neo4jOperations.query( query, "");. From this query I am not able to get User, Friend, Batch objects. will you please relook at my code? Thanks.